# Trouble inserting values into a table in oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

This is my SQL statement:

```
insert into client 1 
    (Nom, prénom, DateNaiss, RUE, CP, Ville)
values 
    ('SALMI','SAMI','02/12/1944','RUE N17',100023,'RABAT');
```

I got this message:

> ORA-00926: missing VALUES keyword

What am I missing?

Comment: what is the name of the table?

Comment: in a comment you say that the table name is "client", your code uses "client 1"... please post the correct table name, even paying attention to upper/lower case

Comment: You're trying to insert the value `1` into `(Nom, prénom, ...`, which makes no sense. Why is that `1` in there?

Answer (score 1):

should be

```
insert into client (Nom,prénom,DateNaiss,RUE,CP,Ville) 
values('SALMI','SAMI','02/12/1944','RUE N17',100023,'RABAT');
```

Comment: thanks i just found it .. i was skipping one values that's why i got that problem i fix it now :) thanks tho

Comment: @HAYTHAM - that can't be true. If you were skipping one value, then you would get a different error message, you wouldn't get "missing VALUES keyword". If that's your attitude towards problem solving, you may not get very far.

Answer (score 0):

the problem is due to wrong table name `client 1`,  replace with `client_1` or `"client 1"` or `client` as you mentioned.

[D e m o](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/97cfa/4)

Comment: Maybe the table name really is "client 1" and the OP need a way to hande this

Comment: @Aleksej yes, "client 1" might be the case, but if you try a table with this syntax(without quotes), you get ORA-00926, i know cause i tried.

Comment: the table name is client

Comment: You can use such a name, you simopy have to handle it with double quotes. For example, this works: `create table "client 1" (a number)`